# IIS path issue when using virtual directory

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis-7, filepath

My Internal website is hosted on IIS server. I have added a virtual directory

```
/Resources
```

with physical path `\\svr-dc\Images\Technical\Done\Resources`
I have given the right path credentials.

When i type`http://intraweb/internaldb/Resources//blue%20shaft.png` in the browser I can see the image. But when my application loads it tries to access the following URL `http://intraweb/Resources//blue%20shaft.png` 
I am clearly missing something very simple here.

I extract the image by doing  query from my SQL database and calling `@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Body)` in my View to display the content. Everything is displayed as it should be with the exception of the image.

Comment: I think you're going to have to provide more information, such as how you are referencing that image in your view/page.

Comment: The path of the image is stored in my SQL database. I extracting it by calling @Html.Raw on my page.

Comment: Update your question with the relevant part of your view.

Comment: @DanielShillcock is this enough information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert your virtual directory into application. Right click on the virtual directory and select 'Convert to application'. Then IIS will serve webrequests related to that application.

Comment: If you are fetching image bytes from DB, convert bytes to base64string and  you should put that in a HTML tag like this.    `<img src="data:image/png;base64,{base64String}" />`

Comment: Harish I don't have permission to alter the content in the SQL.

Comment: Please provide more information on your issue. Can't seem to completely understand what you're trying to achieve. @laz

Comment: I fixed the issue. it turned out to be a problem with the path stored in my database.

Comment: Great. Make sure you always ask the right question.